# TV OS UIFocusEnvironment Not focusing Button

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, uifocusguide

Hi all I am a beginner in TV OS App development.

As mentioned below image, I could move the buttons,

Button1 -> Right Arrow -> focusing Button 2

I have noticed that, When  moving down next (From Button2 to Button4) focusing item frame should be with in the boundary of the Button2 and Button6.

I want to move Button1 to Button 3 when down pressed. (Button3 is not in the boundary between Button1 and Button5)

How do I fix this?

Any help will highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: can u send the storyboard file ?

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi: Solved the issue by using below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can place a `UIFocusGuide` to the left of button 3. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusguide)

The focus guide is a invisible layout guide element that will "catch" focus and redirect it to whatever view you specify.

Edit:
[Full documentation with Sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation/creating_custom_navigation_interactions)

Example:

```swift
let focusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)
focusGuide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button3.rightAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button3.topAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button3.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = [button3]
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. I have edited with sample reference.